# javascript - not quite sure about a few lines of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just started coding and have created a successful program, however I had to research a small block of code in order to make the rest of my code work but I have no idea what the bit of code means. Could some one please help me. Thank you.

This is my block that I don't understand:

```
var changecol = function() {
  $.each(colorinfo, function(grid, colarray) {
    $('#' + grid).css('background-color', colarray[count % colarray.length]);
  });
  count++;
};
setInterval(changecol, 1000);
```

Comment: It's changing the background color on a set of elements. It's not clear what those elements are from the code provided.

Comment: changecolor is a function that sets all the HTMLElement members of `colorinfo` to different color. That function is being called every second changing the colors. However, this is not a good fit for StackOverflow. You have to play around with the code, make changes and see what happens. If you don't understand why something happened, then you have a good SO question

Comment: Which part don't you understand? Have you tried commenting it out to see what changes? Do you not understand the functions? Have you looked up the documentation on, for example, [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)? Properly formatting your code (which I did) helps to see what it does too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organizing a bit your code, there is an extra `});` at the end and after removing it would look like the following:

```
var changecol = function() {
  $.each(colorinfo, function(grid, colarray) {
    $('#' + grid).css('background-color', colarray[count % colarray.length]);
  });  
  count++; 
}; 

setInterval(changecol, 1000);
```

Apparently, every 1 sec is changing the background color of a set of elements which IDs are stored in `colorinfo`

Answer (score 0):

After 1 sec, run **changecol** function which loop through the **colorinfo** variable (must be a jquery returned object).

For each item in **colorinfo**, get its **key** (grid) ans its **value** (colarray).

Then select an HTML element which its **id** is equals the **grid** variable and set its CSS background-color property using an array called **colarray** at the index calculed by `count % colarray.length` which prevent to exceed the array length (once mod (%) return its result division)

Then add 1 to **count** var